# Complex analysis intergation problem $\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Evaluate: $$\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$$

I came across this problem in a complex analysis book and I am thrown off by the notation. The book doesn't have any examples to go off of but am I suppose to compute the integral of $\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$ from (0,2)? Or am I off track?

Comment: $C(0,2)$ is the circle of radius $2$ centred at $0$.

Comment: ok so conceptually I am trying to find the area under $\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$ in $C(0,2)$?

Comment: I think you need Cauchy's formula

Comment: Thanks @Nehorai I will check into that